# Angular Application Refresh stay on the same component

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have an Angular 14 application with a app-routing-module.ts like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: URLS.ROUTE_BASE, component: HomeComponent },
 { path: URLS.ROUTE_BASE + "/", component: HomeComponent },
 { path: URLS.COMPOMENT_ONE, component: ComponentOne },
 { path: URLS.COMPONENT_TWO, component: ComponentTwo },
];
```

From the HomeComponent page, the user is able to navigate to Components 1 & 2.
Components 1 & 2 also have processes which run when they initialize, in their respective OnInit() methods. The requirement is that when the user is on components 1 or two, and they refresh the page in their browser, it should reload the component and they should remain on this page. The methods which are in these components should just trigger again.

The behavior we see currently is that they are redirected back to the HomeComponent, which as I understand is the default behavior.

I have seen some answers which say that this addition is a fix, although I have not seen it in my case. Below is from the app-routing-module.ts:

```
   @NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
      relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I have also seen several explanations on how to *detect* when a refresh is about to happen - so that data can be preserved, etc. I have also seen several examples on *how to* refresh the page. But I am wondering if there is an out-of-the box configuration within Angular to control the behavior of staying on the same component when the user hits refresh, and to stay on whichever component they are currently on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not been clear, but you can do this:

You need have children components related in to rounting module.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    loadChildren: './other/.module#AModule',
    data: {
      preload: false
  }
];
```

... Then, in the OtherModule you need manage your components "A" and "B"

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent,
    data: {
      preload: false
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'b',
    component: BComponent,
    data: {
      preload: false
    }
  }
];
```

... of course you can play with this aproach, you can create a module that contains brother "A" and "B" simultaneously.. and so on...

...or you can manage the URLS from /app-routing.module.ts
You need read more abot angular routing and research for many examples...

This is my github:

https://github.com/HectorRPL

Perhaps you can find something that help you.